# Технологии для реализации проекта

Tags: архитектура, framework, проектирование, фреймворк

Возникла идея реализовать проект, который на выходе должен иметь следующие возможности:

- распространяться как дистрибутив
- кроссплатформенный: возможность установки на linux, windows
- бекенд: компилируемый фреймворк, опыт программирования есть в java, c#, php. Обязательная поддержка Active Record (уж очень нравится реализация eloquent в Laravel). Также необходимо наличие шедуллера, для выполнения задач по расписанию.
- фронт: исключительно vuejs, т.к. есть достаточный опыт
- бд: MySQL, Postgres
- возможности взаимодействия с операционной системой, проверка наличия установленных компонентов для последующего взаимодействия с ними

По сути, проект должен являться неким решением, которое работает с установленными компонентами ос, подготавливает данные для них, выполняет обработку пользовательских данных в этих компонентах и запоминает результаты.

Поскольку это личный проект, ищу бесплатные решения, которые можно будет впоследствии использовать в коммерческих целях. Пересмотрел множество фреймворков для реализации бекенда, например Laravel, Spring, Play framework, но в случае с первым - отсутствие компиляции (не хочу светить код), а Spring и Play имеют достаточно высокий порог входа (одна реализация ролевого доступа чего только стоит, плюс слишком много кода для простых операций и имхо очень сложная архитектура "сцепки" их с vuejs). Хотелось бы иметь возможность доставлять пакеты на фреймворк (и обильный их репозиторий), иметь хорошую документацию, понимать на чем "крутить" фронт, а также как это все объединить в одно коммерческое решение.

Поделитесь ссылками на материалы, в которых описывается подход к реализации такого проекта от стадии проектирования, до стадии продажи, а также информацию о том, как реализовать данный проект своими силами, на какие решения обратить внимание или возможно опыт реализации.

Comment: сразу минус, поскольку это не вопрос, а набор желаний!

Comment: кому бэкенде код светить будешь?

Comment: @exvayn специалистам по ИБ, кому же еще?!

Comment: Товарищи спамеры, пожалуйста не засоряйте тему, если нечего ответить. "Набор желаний" можно отнести к любому вопросу, т.к. если человек ищет решение - это его желание. В моем случае, я ищу решение моей конкретной проблемы и ожидаю услышать совет специалистов, имеющих опыт в данном вопросе

Comment: " Spring и Play имеют достаточно высокий порог входа (одна реализация ролевого доступа чего только стоит" Что вы имеете в виду? В спринге доступ по ролям есть "из коробки", достоточно прочитать соответствующий мануал на офф сайте. Мне часа хватило, чтобы разобраться.